# Merge dataframes with duplicate keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 in the form of:

df1:

```
      a   b  
1     x   bb
2     y   ba
```

I want to merge that with another dataframe df2 that has multiple rows where the column 'a' is matching the index of df1:

df2:

```
      a   c   d   e
1     1   cc  dd  ee
2     1   cd  de  ef
3     1   dd  ef  ff
4     2   ff  fg  fh
5     2   fg  fh  ff
```

I tried merging but I got lots of duplicates for df1 looking like this:

```
      a   b   c   d   e
1     x   bb  cc  dd  ee
1     x   bb  cd  de  ef
1     x   bb  dd  ef  ff

2     y   ba  ff  fg  fh
2     y   ba  fg  fh  ff
```

How can I merge them to achieve something like this:

```
      a   b   c   d   e
1     x   bb  cc  dd  ee
              cd  de  ef
              dd  ef  ff

2     y   ba  ff  fg  fh
              fg  fh  ff
```

I read about stacking but I dont really want to have multiple indices. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the index numbering important?

Comment: I just realized due to your question that I actually made a mistake in my description. df2["a"] is actually refering to the index of df1. So yeah you could say the index is important. I tried your solution approaches but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge these two dataframes using the `pd.merge` method. I assume you want to broadcast the values of `b`. Else please provide a fill-value for `b`.

If you want to have the columns `a` and `b` as part of a `MultiIndex` and retain the index numbering of `df1`, merge the dataframes like this:

```
df_new = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2).set_index(['index', 'a', 'b'])
```

If you want to keep `a` and `b` as columns, merge the dataframes like this:

```
df_new = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2).set_index('index')
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to broadcast the values of b. I just want them once if that is possible.  As in my result the 2nd and 3rd row are supposed to be part of the row with the index number 1 if that helps.